# BLAS daxpy does not add anything, y is unchanged

Tags: fortran, blas

I'm experiencing the following problem:

I am trying to use the BLAS subroutines, however when using them, they don't seem to be working/overwriting the solution, for example, if I try to add two vectors `a` and `b` and run a function with

```
program test
real(kind=8), dimension(:), allocatable :: a,b
integer ::n
print*, "input n, a, b"
read*, n
allocate(a(n), b(n))
read*, a, b
print*, a
print*, b
call daxpy(n,1,a,1,b,1)
print*, a
print*, b
deallocate(a, b)
end program test
```

Then `b` comes out the same both times for non-zero.

I assumed that the subroutine calculates `a+b` then overwrites this to `b`.

I have tried just using `a+b` without any calls to BLAS and that works fine.

Comment: Pleas show us the complete code. See [mcve] and [ask]. It is important to see the variable declarations and their initial values.

Comment: Apologies, i thought it unnecessary, updated now

Comment: As you read input, can you show what that input looks like?

Comment: for example, i would input singleton vectors as 1 5 10 and the the output would just then repeat 5 and 10 twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to pass a double-precision literal (or variable) to "alpha" (for [daxpy](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/468394)):

```
program test
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: dp = kind(0.0d0)  ! for blas
    real(dp), dimension(:), allocatable :: a, b
    integer :: n
    n = 2
    allocate( a(n), b(n) )
    a = 1.0d0   ! or 1.0_dp
    b = 2.0d0
    print *, "b = ", b

      call daxpy( n, 1,     a, 1, b, 1 )   ! case (1)
    ! call daxpy( n, 1.0d0, a, 1, b, 1 )   ! case (2)
                    !^^^^
    print *, "b = ", b
    deallocate( a, b )
end program

Case (1):  // the second "b" usually gives more garbage data like 1.06E+160
 b =    2.0000000000000000        2.0000000000000000     
 b =    2.0000000000000000        2.0000000000000000 

Case (2):
 b =    2.0000000000000000        2.0000000000000000
 b =    3.0000000000000000        3.0000000000000000
```

If we include some interface file for BLAS (e.g., mkl_blas.fi obtained from [MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl) include directory)

```
program test
    implicit none
    include 'mkl_blas.fi'
    ...
```

Case (1) gives an error with (a bit more) explicit messages:

```
test.f90:13:38:

     call daxpy( n, 1,     a, 1, b, 1 )
                                      1
Error: Type mismatch in argument 'da' at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to REAL(8)
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be working now, much appreciated